# Is any of this true about infinite series of functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, roots, absolute-convergence

Let $f_n^+(x)$ be a sequence of non-negative functions $f_n^+: X \to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, such that each $f_n^+$ has countably many zeros.  Then if $f(x) = \sum f_n^+(x)$ converges point-wise, the number of zeroes of $f$ is countable.  Proof: $f^+(x) = 0$ iff $f_n^+(x) = 0, \ \forall n \implies Z(f) = \bigcap Z(f_n^+)$, which is clearly countable.  The converse doesn't seem necc. true.

Obviously we can't say the same about any other level sets of $f^+$.  Imagine the level sets of a continuous mountain.  Each topographical ring around the mountain has size equal to a closed interval of $\Bbb{R}$.

Is'nt that weird?  I must be wrong then...

Comment: By countable, I assume you include finite? (Countable is used ambiguously in literature, sometimes implying countably infinite, sometimes implying at most countably infinite).

Comment: @Tom yes, that's included.

Comment: @Tom, isn't it *weird* that you can prove a countable number of zeros for such functions but not any other level set!  That meas at the base the mountain there can ony be a countable number?  Doesn't seem right!

Comment: You are starting with the assumption that each $f_n^+$ has only countably many zeros. What would the $f_n^+$ represent in your mountain analogy?

Comment: Yeah, I know.  Probably mountains that don't intersect the 0 plane, lols!

Comment: @EnjoysMath This isn`t weird at all. The reason we can prove that property is the positivity of $f_n$ - which is not there anymore when talking about level sets.